# __POSIX_VISIBLE is ruining my BSD sockets on cygwin

Tags: c++, sockets, cmake, cygwin

I'm using cygwin to develop a crossplatform client app that is based on websockets. For unix support I'm trying to use BSD sockets from within a cygwin environment.

The problem is that the compiler includes don't define certain symbols.

E.g. I'm using `struct addrinfo` and the compiler is complaining that

```
/cygdrive/c/dev/supabase-cpp/extern/realtime-cpp/src/port_unix.h:62:5: Fehler: »addrinfo« wurde in diesem Gültigkeitsbereich nicht definiert
   62 |     addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;
      |     ^~~~~~~~
```

Or in english: addrinfo is not defined in this scope.

I've had a look at the includes for the headerfile that is supposed to define addrinfo which is `netdb.h` from in C:\cygwin64\usr\include (there are 4 more versions of this header lying around inside the cygwin tree but AFAIK this is the one the compiler is looking for).

I see that `addrinfo` is defined there but it's guarded by the __POSIX_VISIBLE macro and this is why I'm not getting it.

```
#if __POSIX_VISIBLE >= 200112 && !defined(__INSIDE_CYGWIN_NET__)
struct addrinfo {
  int             ai_flags;     /* input flags */
  int             ai_family;        /* address family of socket */
  int             ai_socktype;      /* socket type */
  int             ai_protocol;      /* ai_protocol */
  socklen_t       ai_addrlen;       /* length of socket address */
  char            *ai_canonname;    /* canonical name of service location */
  struct sockaddr *ai_addr;     /* socket address of socket */
  struct addrinfo *ai_next;     /* pointer to next in list */
};
#endif
```

Because I checked and __POSIX_VISIBLE is set to 0. I had a look at a similarly named topic here [__POSIX_VISIBLE is ruining my pthreading on cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139631/posix-visible-is-ruining-my-pthreading-on-cygwin) and the consensus seems for __POSIX_VISIBLE to be defined the compiler has to be set to -std=gnu++NN. I tried with -std=gnu++14 and -std=gnu++20 like this:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
...
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>:-std=gnu++20>
)
...
```

But nothing worked. I also had a look at `features.h` from usr/include/sys/ where __POSIX_VISIBLE is defined like this:

```
#if (_POSIX_C_SOURCE - 0) >= 200809L
#define __POSIX_VISIBLE     200809
#elif (_POSIX_C_SOURCE - 0) >= 200112L
#define __POSIX_VISIBLE     200112
#elif (_POSIX_C_SOURCE - 0) >= 199506L
#define __POSIX_VISIBLE     199506
#elif (_POSIX_C_SOURCE - 0) >= 199309L
#define __POSIX_VISIBLE     199309
#elif (_POSIX_C_SOURCE - 0) >= 2 || defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE)
#define __POSIX_VISIBLE     199209
#elif defined(_POSIX_SOURCE) || defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE)
#define __POSIX_VISIBLE     199009
#else
#define __POSIX_VISIBLE     0
#endif
```

When I checked within my code __POSIX_VISIBLE is set to 0 so apparently neither _POSIX_SOURCE nor _POSIX_C_SOURCE is set.

How can I set __POSIX_VISIBLE so support for BSD socket is enabled when compiling under cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I checked compiler options with

```
get_target_property(MAIN_CFLAGS ${PROJECT_NAME} COMPILE_OPTIONS)
message("Target compiler flags are ${MAIN_CFLAGS}")
```

However: When I checked the actual build flags using

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

from the build directory, it showed an additional -std=c++20 flag right after -std=gnu++20. I saw that I had

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
```

defined at toplevel and this would add the compiler flag -std=c++20 at build stage (I suppose) as opposed to genereation stage which was confusing. Removed it, now with only `-std=gnu++20` it works and POSIX is visible.

**UPDATE**:

I was stupid because it would work out of the box if I hadn't

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

When I switched it to `ON` CMake chooses GNU++ for gcc compilers...

Comment: You could try with `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED NO)` and `set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS YES)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks I just also came to this solution!

Comment: *One* lesson for today: When posting question, please sure the [mre] shows enough information about your build environment, like your whole `CMakeLists.txt` file. :)